# How can i avoid attributes display all sub categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category, attributes

How can avoid particular attribute display all my sub categories.

**Example:**

Category name **`mobile`** attribute **`brand`**. When i go sub category name "os" right after the attribute display as well as mobile, **i dont want to display brand attribute for my sub category "os**

Comment: Which magento version?

Comment: magento 1.9.2.3

Comment: are u want for backed?

Comment: Just clarify doubt.

Comment: Please put more details other wise question goes to close

Comment: Eg. Category name "mobile" attribute "brand". When i go sub category name "os" right after the attribute display as well as mobile, i dont want to display  attribute brand for my sub category "os".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At backend, the **fields of Category form  are render** by class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes`.

You need to rewrite that block class because of `prepareForm()`  are responsible for render the fields.

At this function using  `removeField()` ,we can remove brand field as per as ,your business

```
<?php
    class Devamitbera_Customcategory_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes
 protected $_MobileCat=15;
   protected function _prepareForm() {
        $group      = $this->getGroup();
        $attributes = $this->getAttributes();

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('group_' . $group->getId());
        $form->setDataObject($this->getCategory());

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('fieldset_group_' . $group->getId(), array(
            'legend'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__($group->getAttributeGroupName()),
            'class'     => 'fieldset-wide',
        ));

        if ($this->getAddHiddenFields()) {
            if (!$this->getCategory()->getId()) {
                // path
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('parent')) {
                    $fieldset->addField('path', 'hidden', array(
                        'name'  => 'path',
                        'value' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('parent')
                    ));
                }
                else {
                    $fieldset->addField('path', 'hidden', array(
                        'name'  => 'path',
                        'value' => 1
                    ));
                }
            }
            else {
                $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array(
                    'name'  => 'id',
                    'value' => $this->getCategory()->getId()
                ));
                $fieldset->addField('path', 'hidden', array(
                    'name'  => 'path',
                    'value' => $this->getCategory()->getPath()
                ));
            }
        }

        $this->_setFieldset($attributes, $fieldset);
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $rootId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;
            /* @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */
            if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'url_key') {
                if (
                    (!$this->getCategory()->getId() && $this->getRequest()->getParam('parent', $rootId) == $rootId)
                    || ($this->getCategory()->getParentId() == $rootId)
                ) {
                    $fieldset->removeField('url_key');
                } else {
                    $form->getElement('url_key')->setRenderer(
                        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_form_renderer_attribute_urlkey')
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        if ($this->getCategory()->getLevel() == 1) {
            $fieldset->removeField('custom_use_parent_settings');
        } else {
            if ($this->getCategory()->getCustomUseParentSettings()) {
                foreach ($this->getCategory()->getDesignAttributes() as $attribute) {
                    if ($element = $form->getElement($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                        $element->setDisabled(true);
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($element = $form->getElement('custom_use_parent_settings')) {
                $element->setData('onchange', 'onCustomUseParentChanged(this)');
            }
        }
        /* Remove at */
        if ($this->getCategory()->getParentId() == $_MobileCat) {
             $fieldset->removeField('brand');
        }
        if ($this->getCategory()->hasLockedAttributes()) {
            foreach ($this->getCategory()->getLockedAttributes() as $attribute) {
                if ($element = $form->getElement($attribute)) {
                    $element->setReadonly(true, true);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!$this->getCategory()->getId()){
            $this->getCategory()->setIncludeInMenu(1);
        }

        $form->addValues($this->getCategory()->getData());

        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_catalog_category_edit_prepare_form', array('form'=>$form));

        $form->setFieldNameSuffix('general');
        $this->setForm($form);

        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form::_prepareForm();
    }


?>
```

Comment: hi amit : How can i Hide selected attributes for selected categories of products